# How to run a loop SQL with multiple children tables

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, join

I am having difficulty trying to come up with a query that gives me the information I need from multiple tables to create a report. I am trying to get a list by property with rules that are configured (property, ruleset, Ruleitem) and seeing how many times they are applied (Propertyrule,Employeeset , Employeerule)

For example, if I have:

```
          Table A (property), 
          Table B(Ruleset), 
          Table C(RuleItem), 
          Table D(Propertyrule)
          Table E(Employeeset)
          Table F(Employeerule).
```

I want the query to select the ID from the first row from Table A then select the first row from table B based on the ID pulled from table A, then select the ID from the first row of table B, and select all the returns from from table C with the same id from table B. Now I want to count how many rows the table B (Ruleset) appears in each of the tables D, E, and F in their own separate columns.

Once that runs for each row in Column C, then it goes back to column B and loops again. This would be repeated until every row in Table A has been gone through.

Here is what I have, which seems far off from what I need:

```
DECLARE @propid INT

DECLARE c1 CURSOR
FOR
SELECT ID
FROM property --This is the property to copy interfaces into

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT
FROM c1
INTO @propid

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @propid
        ,p.name
        ,rs.propertyid
        ,rs.name
        ,rs.ruletypecode
        ,ri.ruleclasscode
        ,ri.name
        ,esr.EmployeeSetID
        ,pr.rulesetid AS propertyrule
        ,(
            SELECT count(rulesetid)
            FROM employeerule
            )
    FROM ruleset rs
    JOIN ruleitem ri ON ri.RuleSetID = rs.id
    JOIN property p ON p.id = rs.PropertyID
    LEFT JOIN employeesetrule esr ON esr.rulesetid = rs.id
    LEFT JOIN propertyrule pr ON pr.RuleSetID = rs.id
    LEFT JOIN employeerule er ON er.RuleSetID = rs.id
    WHERE rs.id IN (
            SELECT rulesetid
            FROM employeesetrule
            )
        OR rs.id IN (
            SELECT rulesetid
            FROM propertyrule
            )
        OR rs.id IN (
            SELECT rulesetid
            FROM employeerule
            )

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM c1
    INTO @propid
END

CLOSE c1

DEALLOCATE c1
```

[Example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZXyY.png)

Comment: Regardless of the question goal, I highly do not recommend you use cursor in this query as it will make it very slow to get this report. Please provide examples of Input data to make it easier to help you as you have complicated questions. Last thing, are you allowed to use scalar functions inside your query?

Comment: I am not exactly seeing need of a loop for this solution. Also, you do not use the loop variable @propid to filter query, only as a scalar in `SELECT`. Sample data in all relevant tables can help us craft a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure the needs of cursor looping but assuming `property` table contains unique listing of properties (i.e., `p.id`), consider a single query joining on aggregate queries for counts in other tables. Comments indicate each of needs being potentially met (with caps for subtle change):

```
SELECT p.id,                          -- select EACH ID from Table A
       , p.name
       , rs.propertyid
       , rs.name AS ruleset_name
       , rs.ruletypecode
       , ri.ruleclasscode             -- select all the returns from table C
       , ri.name AS ruleitem_name
       , es_agg.employeeset_count     -- count how many rows the table B (Ruleset) appears in tables D in separate column
       , pr_agg.propertrule_count     -- count how many rows the table B (Ruleset) appears in tables E in separate column
       , er_agg.employeerule_count    -- count how many rows the table B (Ruleset) appears in tables F in separate column

FROM property p 
INNER JOIN ruleset rs
       ON p.id = rs.PropertyID        -- select EACH row from table B based on the ID pulled from table A
INNER JOIN ruleitem ri 
       ON ri.RuleSetID = rs.id         
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT rulesetid, COUNT(*) AS employeeset_count  
     FROM employeesetrule
     GROUP BY rulesetid) es_agg
       ON rs.id = es_agg.rulesetid
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT rulesetid, COUNT(*) AS propertrule_count
     FROM propertyrule
     GROUP BY rulesetid) pr_agg
       ON rs.id = pr_agg.rulesetid
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT rulesetid, COUNT(*) AS employeerule_count
     FROM employeerule
     GROUP BY rulesetid) er_agg
       ON rs.id = er_agg.rulesetid
```